# How to get image file comment (and – optionally – other file properties) in NTFS file system (Windows 10 64-bit) with VBA

Tags: vba, total-commander

I have a number of jpg files supplied with comments. How can I read a comment attached to such file into a variable for further use with VBA?

I have searched the web, but no solution helped me to solve the problem. For instance, I could get a list of all properties of the file with SHELL32.Folder and SHELL32.FolderItem, but no actual values for comments could be obtained although such comments were clearly visible in Total Commander and other file browsers.

Comment: Can you see the text of the comments in the 'details pane' in File Explorer when you select the file? Are the comments next to the "Comments:" label?

Comment: Thanks for your interesting question: strangely enough the comment is not visible in MSW File Explorer, but it is visible in Total Commander. Sorry, I am not sure how to insert relevant screenshots into my answer. Now I see that TC seems to use descript.ion file to hold comments. Does it mean that they are not actually embedded in the related file body?

Comment: Sorry, no experience of Total Commander. I could give you a solution to get the comment text if it is embedded as an extended property of the JPG file itself (and so would be visible in File Explorer), but it's not gonna work if it is in a separate file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810398/descript-ion-file-spec

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. They appeared really helpful and insightful. Now I understand why my previous attempts ocurred futile. I will work on the issue, but it’s now enough clear to me due to your guidance.